# SSRS passing multi-value parameter in stored procedure, still got issues

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, ssrs-2012

I'm passing in multiple values to a `Stored Procedure` using this answer here to split the list: [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0ead7ceb-3fdd-4625-aa82-1d4195f984b1/passing-multivalue-parameter-in-stored-procedure-ssrs][1]
as well as this 
`CHARINDEX(',' + MyTable.Field1 + ',', ',' + @param + ',') > 0`.

Both options give me the same result but not the result I'm looking for.
For example I chose 5 values from `MyTable.Field1`, only 2 are returned. In another case I chose 3 but it returned only 1. I have been able to choose 2 values and return 2. It is really frustrating.
If I execute the `SELECT` statement in the `Stored Procedure` with hard-coded values like this 
`WHERE MyTable.Field1 IN ('Apple','Orange','Pear','Banana')`
all is well. The `SQL Profiler` shows me this when executing the report through SSRS:
`exec MyProc @param=N'Apple,Orange,Pear,Banana'`

Comment: Need to see the sql you are using .

Comment: Hangs head in shame. In order to send you the sql I reworked the stored procedure down to the minimum, that's when I realised that the parameter got truncated! Because I used a single value first the length was only 15 but once I selected multiple values that wasn't enough. I will get a mod to delete this question. Thanks Coder of Code you did help me a lot.